# how to store value in dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, combobox

I have created a windows form application with the following `get set` method. The `name, email` and `phone` is hardcoded and thus the value can be stored by creating an object

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<String, String> facilities { get; set; }


    Rating r = new Rating(); //object creating
        r.Name = txtName.Text; //get value from textbox and assing to property
        r.Email = txtEmail.Text;
        r.Phone = txtPhone.Text;
```

However for the facilities, comboBox is used where the data comes from txt file

```
       int locationX = 143;
        int locationY = 200;
        string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(@"facilities.txt");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // Remove the extra ','
            string comboName = line.Substring(0, line.Length - 1);

            ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
            comboBox.Name = comboName;
            comboBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
            comboBox.Location = new Point(locationX, locationY);
            
            this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(comboBox);

            Label label = new Label();
            label.Text = comboName;
            label.Location = new Point(0, locationY);
            
            this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(label);


            locationY += 50;
        }

        file.Close();
      }
```

How can I store its data in the dictionary?
I tried using the same concept

```
             ComboBox parking= (ComboBox)this.Controls.Find("parking facility", true)[0];
          //MessageBox.Show(parking.Text);
         r.facilities.Add("parking facility", parking.Text);
```

but got System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error

Comment: What is `Rating` and is `r.facilities` initialized before adding something?

Comment: Where do you create a combobox with name `parking facility`? Do you want to display all the facilities in one combobox?

Comment: no one facility in one comboBox
i was trying to get the value and store in dictionar.

Comment: Indeed, `facilities` is never instantiated and the starting value is the default `null` reference. So you need to create an object as indicated by @noviceinDotNet

Comment: yes i got it thank you so much for helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

initialization necessary for enumerable objects.

```
r.facilities = new Dictionary <String,String>();
r.facilities.Add ("parking facility", parking.Text);
```

Comment: Also OP can use default value like `public Dictionary<String, String> facilities { get; set; } = new Dictionary <String,String>();` and add the `readonly` modifier if relevant.